# Searching multiple sections of UITableView, array of array structs

Tags: arrays, swift, tableview

Amateur here. I'd really like to be able to search through my contacts tableview controller i've created. I've been trying out all sorts of different ideas the last few days and nothing has stuck. It seems all I can find is how to search an Array, but my sections seem to throw it all off and I'm just not smart enough to know the code to fix. I've got Contacts VC that derives data from a struct and then an array of 3 arrays. I've got an array of arrays in order to have sections in my Tableview.

struct Contacts {

```
var name = String()
var cellPhone = String()
var pager = String()
```

}

```
var contacts = [
    [Contacts(name: "Name", cellPhone: "Number", pager: "Number"),
     Contacts(name: "Name", cellPhone: "Number", pager: "Number") ],

     [Contacts(name: "Name", cellPhone: "Number", pager: "Number"),
      Contacts(name: "Name", cellPhone: "Number", pager: "Number") ],

     [Contacts(name: "Name", cellPhone: "Number", pager: "Number"),
     Contacts(name: "Name", cellPhone: "Number", pager: "Number") ]]
```

In my Contacts TableViewController I've added a SearchBar and defined a new variable.

```
  var filteredContacts = [[Contacts]]()
```

and added this function

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    if searchController.searchBar.text! == "" || searchController.searchBar.text == nil {
        isSearching = false
        filteredContacts = contacts
    } else {
        // Filter the results
        isSearching = true

        filteredContacts = [contacts.joined().filter { $0.name.lowercased().contains(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased()) }]
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}




override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return myTitles.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if isSearching {
        return filteredContacts.count
    }
    return contacts[section].count

}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    if isSearching {
        cell.column1.text = self.filteredContacts[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].name   
        cell.column2.text = self.filteredContacts[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].cellPhone
        cell.column3.text = self.filteredContacts[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].pager


    } else {
    cell.column1.text = contacts[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].name   
    cell.column2.text = contacts[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].cellPhone
    cell.column3.text = contacts[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].pager
    }

    return cell


}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    return myTitles[section]
}
```

Comment: numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView)  should return value based on whether you want to show filtered contacts or complete contacts. What is this myTitles?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I assume you want the search results to still be in sections, and not one long list. If so, this might be your problem: The contacts model used to populate the tableview when isSearching is false is a nested array. But the filteredContacts ends up being a simple array. As a result, when the app wants to draw cells in a specific section (see numberOfRowsInSection), the total cells is always going to be the total contacts in the array, rather than the total in the section. If that makes sense I will write up an answer with tips on how to do that.

Comment: number of sections should be also based on if you want to search or not

Comment: Yes that makes sense. I’m confusing myself with the arrays and how to pull out the nested array objects. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

@thecloud_of_unknowing

I took what you said and added this:

```
 override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if isSearching {
        return filteredContacts.count
    }

    return contacts.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if isSearching {
        return filteredContacts[section].count
    }
    return contacts[section].count

}
```

The hardest part of the whole thing was figuring out the syntax for the searchBar updating function and how to filter a nested array. So just in case anyone else was wondering. Honestly I still do not full understand how it all is working, but I'll get there.

The section title doesn't change, but at least I can search.

```
filteredContacts = [contacts.joined().filter { $0.name.lowercased().contains(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased()) }]
```